# Can Lee Sin reactivate his Q on untargetable target?

Tags: league-of-legends

Scenario:

> Fizz is happily farming in mid lane, suddenly lee sin comes to gank him and hits his Q. Fizz thinks lets GTFO and jump on his troll pole (E).

So we now have an untargetable fizz with a lee sin Q on his head.

Will lee sin be able to reactivate his Q and fly towards fizz?
I understand that it won't to do any damage, but will he move towards fizz?

Answer (score 4):

No he can't while the target is untargetable!

You can't press Q again while the target is in zhonya for instance.

However you can press it right before and lee will still gapclose to the target, but the target will take no damage.

Comment: Do you have any proof or references? Zhonya make you invulnerable (no dmg from dot's and such) so that might have a different ruling?

Comment: When fizz presses e, he isn't considered invulnerable, but out of range of anything (which is why he still takes damage from ignite or so). when fizz was released it made some bug, because his hitbox was put randomly on the map far away from him (some skillshot could hit him on dragon pit while wizz was top for instance). They fixed it but the idea is the same and lee can't press Q when target is out of range or indestructible. If you need a proof just test in custom game :)

Comment: (actually this is a bit more complex but this is the explanation for lee's Q ;) )

Comment: Fizz's E functions the same like Vladimir's pool. Spells will never do damage, including Karthus' ult, but tether abilities like Fiddle's Drain or Leblancs chain will still affect him. I'm not sure if the second part of LeBlancs actually snares and deals damage though, but I don't think it does.

Comment: @Bl00dylicious It does still snare, and damage.